# If file modification date is older than N days

Tags: bash

This question pertains to taking action if a file has a modification date older than so many days. I'm sure it would be similar for creation date or access date, but for modification date, if I have:

```
file=path-name-to-some-file
N=100  # for example, N is number of days
```

How would I do:

```
if file modification time is older than N days
then
fi
```

Comment: bash itself doesn't provide the tools you need -- one additionally needs components (like `stat` or `find`) provided by your operating system. Please update this question to tag in a specific OS, to indicate that it's acceptable for an answer to work only on GNU systems, or to indicate that you need to be compatible with all POSIX platforms.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Several approaches are available. One is just to ask `find` to do the filtering for you:

```
if [[ $(find "$filename" -mtime +100 -print) ]]; then
  echo "File $filename exists and is older than 100 days"
fi
```

---

Another is to use GNU date to do the math:

```
# collect both times in seconds-since-the-epoch
hundred_days_ago=$(date -d 'now - 100 days' +%s)
file_time=$(date -r "$filename" +%s)

# ...and then just use integer math:
if (( file_time <= hundred_days_ago )); then
  echo "$filename is older than 100 days"
fi
```

---

If you have GNU stat, you can ask for a file's timestamp in seconds-since-epoch, and do some math yourself (though this will potentially be a bit off on the boundary cases, since it's counting seconds -- and not taking into account leap days and such -- and not rounding to the beginning of a day):

```
file_time=$(stat --format='%Y' "$filename")
current_time=$(( date +%s ))
if (( file_time < ( current_time - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 100 ) ) )); then
  echo "$filename is older than 100 days"
fi
```

---

Another option, if you need to support non-GNU platforms, is to shell out to Perl (which I'll leave it to others to demonstrate).

If you're interested more generally in getting timestamp information from files, and portability and robustness constraints surrounding same, see also [BashFAQ #87](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087).

Comment: @MaheshKharvi, the correction is appreciated, but please keep the reasoning behind the edit in the metadata text, or as a hidden comment in the source (using `<!-- comment here -->` syntax); putting it in huge bold print in the post itself can be considered defacement, and is probably why the initial suggestion was rejected.

Comment: i'm confused: shebang?

Comment: @flobee, the shebang is the line at the top of a script on UNIX that describes the interpreter to run it with. For example, `#!/bin/bash` is a shebang that specifies that a script be run with bash, whereas `#!/bin/sh` lets it be run with any POSIX sh interpreter (which may not support bash extensions).

Comment: @flobee, ...that said, I don't see the word "shebang" anywhere in the answer, so I'm not quite clear on where the confusion came from.

Comment: i ask because some of the snipet dont work in bash, anyway i got it now after rewire for me, thx, shbang and bash version... GNU bash gave some hints... :)

Comment: With the stat version. Is the + in the format really necessary? file_time=$(stat --format='+%Y' "$filename") outputs "+" in front of the timestamp.

Comment: @arielf, that's a useful error, isn't it? Otherwise, how is a user of your script supposed to know what's wrong when an assumption it made about filenames is false? (If the script *intends* to handle the no-such-file case, then it would make sense for it to do that explicitly, before running `find`). In general, I consider blindly redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` malpractice (and in-and-of-itself justification for failing code review) just like catching `Exception` in Python or Java.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised no one mentioned this method - it's hiding right there in `man test`, implied by `-nt` and `-ot`, so I suspect it's been there for a long time:

```
N_DAYS_AGO=/tmp/n-days-ago.$$
touch -d "$N days ago" $N_DAYS_AGO
if [ "$myfile" -ot "$N_DAYS_AGO" ]; then
   ...
fi
```

Comment: Don't be surprised. The author was asking for a bash way, but touch is not a built-in. touch on AIX or Solaris and Mac may not have the `-d` option. I just checked for AIX.

Answer (score 3):

I found another great answer to the question. We use `find` with the `-newerXY` option. Here is an example:

```sh
if [[ ! $(find "$file" -newermt "8 hours ago") ]]; then
    echo "File can't be older than 8 hours: $file"
    exit 1
fi
```

Found it here: https://superuser.com/a/1106706/1090383

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other solution? This only works with GNU find which is not available everywhere, e.g. on AIX: 
find "$file" -newermt "8 hours ago"
find: 0652-017 -newermt is not a valid option.

Comment: Is `stat` and `date` available on AIX? In that case you can use the approach described in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32019461/7391331

Comment: stat: no. istat does not accept formatting parameters.
date does not accept +%s on older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary file, then set it's time to N days ago. Compare your file with the temporary file.

```
N=100
rf=/tmp/temp1234
echo "temporary file" &> $rf
touch -d "$N days ago" $rf
for myfile in $(find . -type f); do
    if [[ $rf -nt $myfile ]]; then
        echo "$myfile is older than $N days."
    else
        echo "$myfile is not too old."
    fi
done
```