# bash script to remove all directories created before a certain date

Tags: bash, shell

I have a set of backup directories and I would like to write a bash script to remove all directories created before let's say 22/11. How can I achieve that ?

my directories are in this syntax

```
backup-{timestamp}
```

eg:

```
backup-20200514100830
```

Comment: You can use `find` with `mtime`  fot this. Check this thread --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599094/explaining-the-find-mtime-command

Comment: @Ehsansarshar : So for defining the "creation time", you are not interested in any actual timestamp, but want to derive it from the directory name, right? You better also say what operating system you are running.

Comment: I was searching for a way to find directories by directory name. but I think mtime is the solution

Comment: @Ehsansarshar : _mtime_ is not the **creation** time of the directory, but if you are happy with this, it's ok.

Comment: You may take also advantage of [If file ... date is older than n days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019432/).